# how to simplify use of pathlib objects to work with functions looking for strings

Tags: python, python-2.7

I quite like using pathlib for path management in python, but the drawback of using this package is that a lot of commands, like `shutil.copy`, `.move`, the 
builtin `open` requires a string and not a PosixPath object, giving as error

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, PosixPath found
```

The logical solution is of course to use `str()`.

My question is how would it be possible (if it would be) to modify pathlib objects such that a call like `open(pathlib.PosixPath)` would work without the use of `str()`.

Comment: Find the location of `open(str_path)` in the source code of library and then add one line at top of this function, `str_path = str(path)`, In this way if you pass a posixPath then it would be converted to `str` implicitly and if a `str` is passed already then there would be no change.

Answer (score 8):

The answer by @Navith is what you should now do in python 3.4. However, [PEP-519](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0519/) is proposed and accepted in python 3.6 to address this valid concern.

> This PEP proposes a protocol for classes which represent a file system path to be able to provide a str or bytes representation. *Changes to Python's standard library are also proposed to utilize this protocol where appropriate* to facilitate the use of path objects where historically only str and/or bytes file system paths are accepted.

So in python 3.6 the standard library methods you refer to [now accept Paths](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0519/#implementation), and the answer to your question is use python 3.6.

Comment: This is a great addition to the standard library. Unfortunately, it still leaves a lot of third party libraries that expect string paths. I guess we need to point them to PEP-519 and ask them to support Pathlike objects. It would be nice if there were a cleaner workaround than remembering to put `str` everywhere.

Answer (score 5):

[`Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path) objects have [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.open), [`rmdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rmdir), [`chmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.chmod), ... methods that work the way you'd expect.

```
>>> import pathlib
>>> a_path = pathlib.Path("a.txt")
>>> a_txt = a_path.open("w", encoding="UTF-8")
>>> a_txt
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='a.txt' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

Comment: Ops, didn't notice the open method. Still, it doesn't solve the problems for other functions, like copying, moving  etc etc.

Comment: Functions like `shutil.move` rely on C-programmed functions that don't bother to `str()` something before giving up. Manual conversion seems to be the only solution for those kinds of functions.

Comment: Even subclassing `collections.UserString`, `Path`, and `PurePosixPath` and sending that to something like `shutil.move` will just raise an illegal type exception from `os.rename`.